# Simulating Gravity in C# : Error with my approach or implementation?

Tags: c#, physics, game-physics

I am trying to make a simple 2D physics engine.  The engine defines the gravity to be 10 units at 90 degrees (which is straight down).  In the universe, there are physics entities that each have a velocity made up of speed and direction.  Each time the entities update, I add the gravity vector to the velocity vector of each entity.

If the entity is stationary or is moving parallel to the gravity vector it falls down, otherwise it half works.  What I mean by that is, say and object is shot at a 45 degree angle above the surface, it will go up, curve to the vertex, and then continue parallel to the surface.  The gravity seems to change the velocity as it goes up, but does not make the object ever fall back down.

I was wondering if there was something wrong with the approach I am taking to solve this, or if there is something wrong with the implementation of my solution in the code.

Update Function:

```
public static void UpdateAll()
    {

        foreach (var entity in Entities)
        {
            entity.Velocity.AddVector(Universe.Gravity.Speed, Universe.Gravity.Direction);
        }

        var iterator = 1;
        foreach (var entity in Entities)
        {

            for (var index = iterator; index < Entities.Count; index++)
            {
                //Collision Detection
            }

            entity.Update();

            iterator++;
        }
    }
```

Add Vector Function:

```
public void AddVector(float speed, int direction)
    {
        var radiansA = Angles.DegreesToRadians(SetDirection);
        var radiansB = Angles.DegreesToRadians(direction);

        var vAx = SetSpeed * (float) Math.Cos(radiansA);
        var vAy = SetSpeed * (float) Math.Sin(radiansA);
        var vBx = speed * (float) Math.Cos(radiansB);
        var vBy = speed * (float) Math.Sin(radiansB);

        var magX = vAx + vBx;
        var magY = vAy + vBy;

        var magnitude = (float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(magX, 2) + Math.Pow(magY, 2));

        var theta = Angles.RadiansToDegrees((float) Math.Atan2(magY, magX));

        SetSpeed = magnitude;
        SetDirection = theta;
    }
```

EDIT: I removed the if statements as suggested by some of the comments, but the result is still the same.

**SOLVED:** The error with the code was pointed out in the comments, and I updated the add function to reflect the changes needed.

Comment: It's actually alot easier if you use _vectors_ to start with.  Not sure why the need for the `if` stuff

Comment: it was part of the project specs to have velocity be a magnitude and direction.  The `if` is there in case the object does not have velocity.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam If you used vectors, you could still get the magnitude and direction of the vector runtime. You could use properties to make it transparent.

Comment: Ease of doing the calculation set aside, the vectors can be derived from the information that I have, but something has to be wrong somewhere here.  I don't really want to change my velocity objects to be [x,y] because I'd have to change lots of other code that I have in other classes

Comment: Vectors do fit your spec: they have magnitude and direction, just represented as x and y components instead of angle and magnitude. I think you should change this in your project (and properly encapsulate it), the sooner the better. However, this SO question about adding angle-magnitudes might still be useful.

Comment: I can't properly test right now, but check `Math.Atan2` rather than `Math.Acos` to get your final angle back out. Also, some proper test cases would be a good idea.

Comment: That did work, I changed `Math.Acos` to `Math.Atan2` and `-theta` to `theta` and now it works perfectly.  How do I go about selecting an answer that was done in a comment?

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam _"it was part of the project specs to have velocity be a magnitude and direction"_ - what do you think a vector is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need to test for the direction. The gravity vector should be added, no matter how the object is moving. If it is moving up, it will be slowed down. If it moving down, it will accelerate. If it moving horizontally or not moving at all, it will start falling. In any case this is achieved by adding the gravity vector.

The speed should be a vector as well. It should have an x and a y component. Then all these "direction" stuff could just be dropped. Consequently use vectors defined by x and y everywhere. All speed calculations will then be reduced to simple vector additions. This makes all the math much simpler than using angles.

```
public struct Vector
{
    public Vector(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);
    }

    public float Magnitude
    {
        get
        {
            int d = X * X + Y * Y;
            if (d == 1 || d == 0) {
                return d;
            } else {
                return (float)Math.Sqrt(d);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Vector({X}, {Y})";
    }
}
```

There is also no need to calculate the magnitude and the angle after each speed change. Just get these values from the vector when you need them from appropriate properties. (Just added a Magnitude property as an example)

```
Vector speed, gravity;
...
//Calculate new speed: 
speed += gravity;
```

Another useful operator overload is the multiplication of a vector by a constant

```
public static Vector operator *(double c, Vector a)
{
    return new Vector((int)Math.Round(c * a.X), (int)Math.Round(c * a.Y));
}
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the accepted answer because anyone else trying to do this in the future will find your solution very useful. It did not help me with my particular issue, but I am going to add this to my velocity class for sure.

Comment: The use of `int` for the components of the vector seems wildly inappropriate here.  `float` or `double` would be a better choice.

Comment: I see three possible sources for your error. **1.** There is a logical error in the calculations. **2.** The integer math somewhere truncates something to become 0, e.g. 1/2*5 == 0, because 1/2 is performed as integer division and yields 0. **3.** The collision detection detects a collision when it should not.

Comment: the error was I was using `Math.Acos` instead of `Math.Atan2`

Comment: I must have forgotten my math, but doesn't a vector need to somehow specify a direction?  How is that accomplished with a single x,y coordinate?

Comment: direction: atan2(y, x), length: sqrt(x^2+y^2). The x and y coordinates contain all the information about a vector. You can express a vector by its coordinates or by its argument (that's how the direction angle is also called) and length.

Comment: See: [Cartesian and Polar Coordinates](http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/vec/cartesian_polar.html)